# filter rows based on multiple strings with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

If I have a Pandas DataFrame like this :

```
id     fruits
01     Apple, Apricot
02     Apple, Banana, Clementine, Pear
03     Orange, Pineapple, Pear
04
```

How can i filter rows which contains Apricot, Orange and Pineapple and get following dataframe? Thanks.

```
id     fruits
01     Apple, Apricot
03     Orange, Pineapple, Pear
```

Comment: Those are strings?

Comment: Have your fruits in a list of strings and then use the solution above

Comment: Yes, i think so.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know deal with this error? ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values. I try dropna, it doesn't work out.

Comment: @ahbon add parameter `na=False` to `str.contains`

Comment: Thanks guys. This one seems worked perfectly. df[(df['fruits'].str.contains('Apricot|Orange|Pineapple', na=False))]